# File cannot be saved using multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I'm trying to upload a file using Axios, Multer and Reactjs.

Client side:

```
<input type= "file" name="file" onChange= {this.uploadImage}/>
```

`UploadImage` code:

```
uploadImage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file",  e.target.files[0]); 
    var file = e.target.files[0];  
    let data = new FormData()
    data.set('file',file)
    axios.post( `${apiUrl}/file`, data )
         .then((result) => {
               console.log('succeess' , result)
         })
         .catch((err) => { 
              console.log('errr', err )
         })
```

All it's okay, it shows success log.

Server side: `ProductRoute.js`:

```
const ProductRoute = express.Router();
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads /'});   
ProductRoute.route('/file') 
.post(upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
    console.log("log", req.file );  
})
```

PS: uploads is in the same folder as ProductRoute.js

Here is the console log :

[image: Log]

But, I get no file saved in uploads folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the complete code of your client side html?

Comment: yeah, i "ve updated.